# Python: not all arguments converted during string formatted

Tags: python, html, string, raspberry-pi

```
import datetime

now = datetime.date.today()
now = str(now)
index = open('/var/www/index.html', 'a')
index.write('<br> $s,' %now)
index.close()
```

I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct format:

```
index.write('<br> %s,' %now)
```

That's `%s`, not `$s`.

Answer (score 1):

```
index.write('<br> {now},'.format(now=now))
```

`.format` is much better than `string-formatting`  see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)